# How do I reinstall Windows 11 from Ubuntu when it doesn't recognize any WiFi networks?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-11

I have an HP Envy x360 that I just bought and immediately put Ubuntu on. Due to various issues, such as the speakers not working with Linux, I plan to return it, so I'm trying to put Windows 11 back on it. I created the boot drive using Ventoy, but now I can't actually set it up because it says it requires an internet connection, but doesn't show any networks. I assume this is related to an issue I was having on Ubuntu where it would always start in airplane mode.

Also, the mouse and the touch screen don't work at all for setup.

I saw a suggestion to open terminal with Shift + F10, which works, then change a setting to not require internet, but I can't type anything at all into the terminal.

Also, it still boots to the GRUB terminal every time, so I have to go to the boot menu with Esc to boot into the Windows setup.

Could this all be due to using Ventoy to make the drive instead of the Microsoft tool?

I'm thinking to try making a drive for an earlier Windows which doesn't require internet, setting up, then upgrading to 11.

Anyone know how I could get this working without making a new drive?

Comment: If you bought the PC new, then it likely came with a recovery disk; there may still be a recovery partition on the drive, too. It is also possible to download the recovery disk or to buy it as a CD: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Order-Recovery-Disc-for-HP-ENVY-x360-15m-dr0012dx/td-p/7757281. You can also use another Windows PC to make a USN drive with the Windows 11 ISO using the media creation tool. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Order-recovery-media-from-HP-ENVY-x360-15-ar001ur-USB/td-p/6379551

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the tips. I'll be trying the HP Recovery Tool tomorrow.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The HP recovery tool worked like a charm. If you want to make your comment an answer, I can mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bought the PC new, then it likely came with a recovery disk; there may still be a recovery partition on the drive, too. It is also possible to download the recovery disk [or to buy it as a CD](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Order-Recovery-Disc-for-HP-ENVY-x360-15m-dr0012dx/td-p/7757281) or in [another format](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Order-recovery-media-from-HP-ENVY-x360-15-ar001ur-USB/td-p/6379551).

You can also use another Windows PC to make a USB drive with the Windows 11 ISO at [Download Windows 11 Disk Image (ISO) for x64 devices](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11/). See [PureInfoTech](https://pureinfotech.com/create-bootable-windows-11-usb-install-media/) for creating the USB with Rufus, though Windows own [Media Creation Tool](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/windows-11-media-creation-tool/#ftoc-heading-2) is quite reliable.

*General advice:* The first thing I do after buying a new PC is to make an exact disk image, e.g. with [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5442-macrium-reflect-free.html) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/), booted and run from a [Rescue Environment](https://www.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61) USB drive made on another PC.

- *Then* I [remove all unwanted applications and games](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-remove-bloatware-from-windows-10/) (AKA "bloatware").
- *Then* I  make changes to the OS, such as [disabling some services](https://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/) and [increasing security and privacy](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10).
- *Then* I make *another* disk image.
- *Finally*, I install other operating systems.

It takes less than an hour, unattended, to make an image *and to verify it*, and this procedure has saved me *many* hours trying to get back a working PC after I've made some misteak (ooops...).